# MySQL Select Count of Duplicate Value In Relation Table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables: foods, order_detail, and orders

Here are the records for table `foods`:

```
id    | name       | type
------------------------------
F01   | Omelette   | Breakfast
F02   | Burger     | Breakfast
F03   | Satay      | Lunch
F04   | Fried Rice | Dinner
```

Here are the records for table `order_detail`:

```
food_id    | order_id
-----------------------------
F01        | T01
F04        | T01
F02        | T02
F03        | T03
F03        | T04
```

And here are the records for `orders` table:

```
order_id    | date       | qty
---------------------------------
T01         | 2017-05-01 | 2
T02         | 2017-05-02 | 1
T03         | 2017-05-05 | 1
T04         | 2017-05-07 | 1
```

I want to show count order detail grouped by food type. I expected this result:

```
type       | total_order
-------------------------
Breakfast  | 2
Lunch      | 2
Dinner     | 1
```

Here is my approach, but it still doesn't show the expected result.

```
SELECT
f.type,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM order_detail od WHERE f.id = od.food_id) AS total_order
FROM foods f
LEFT JOIN order_detail od ON f.id = od.food_id
GROUP BY f.type
ORDER BY f.id
```

The result is:

```
type       | total_order
-------------------------
Breakfast  | 1
Lunch      | 2
Dinner     | 1
```

How can I get the result I want? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregation can work here, but you need to join across all three tables:

```sql
SELECT f.type, COUNT(o.order_id) AS total_order
FROM foods f
LEFT JOIN order_detail od ON od.food_id = f.id
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.order_id = od.order_id
GROUP BY f.type
ORDER BY f.id;
```

Note that we do a left join across all three tables in order to not drop any food type which might happen to have zero orders.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the orderdtails to the subselect to get the correct number

```
SELECT
f.type,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM order_detail od2 
 WHERE f.id = od2.food_id AND od2.order_id = od.order_id 
) AS total_order
FROM foods f
LEFT JOIN order_detail od ON f.id = od.food_id
GROUP BY f.type
ORDER BY f.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT type
    FROM foods
    INNER JOIN order_detail ON (order_detail.food_id=foods.id)
    INNER JOIN orders ON (order_detail.ord_id=orders.ord_id)
)
SELECT DISTINCT type, COUNT(type) OVER (PARTITION BY type) AS qty
FROM cte
```